# read "about config" prefrences of mozilla firefox using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, preferences, mozilla

I want to know that how can I read the `about:config` preferences of Mozilla Firefox ? Please note that I do not want to change its value, I only want to read them.

I've already gone through 
[about-config-preferences-and-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796084/about-config-preferences-and-js)

but  I end up following error.
`RefrenceError: getPrefs is not defined`.

Will anyone help to get me out from this?

Comment: what are you trying to acomplish by reading the prefs ?

Comment: While accessing to https protocol, firefox checks the value of one preference and throws an error. I want to check that value before firefox and want to stop request execution.

Comment: in new tab if you open the console and write script there, it will be accesible, but if you load any page then it will not be accesible. see : https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/938251

Comment: i think in ur firefox you have installed some addon which is causing this issue, try different machine

Comment: nop, its not a problem about machine. Its a possibility and we want to put precautions in our project so that users can be informed on such issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible as a security measure

If the browser configuration is exposed to client code like javascript then it could modify the setting to create/expose vulnerabilities

Comment: Please refer the link I've shared in question. Though its tweaky but it is possible.

Comment: that was in terms of firefox addons

Comment: Arun and @Anil Yes, it seems impossible to execute from a web page. We can execute it from an add-on SDK, in other way we can put a JS file which will be invoked on firefox startup.